# Unexpected results from a function

Tags: javascript, function, return-value

I have the following two blocks of code that I am trying to debug.

```
function getSectionId(target){
  let element = target;
  if(element.hasAttribute('id')){
    console.log(element.id); 
    return element.id;
  } 
  else {
    getSectionId(element.parentElement);
  }
};
```

```
function coverageLimitHandler(event) {
  const target = event.target;
  if (target.getAttribute('data-status') !== 'set') {
    let itemBlock = addLineItem();
    let sectionId = getSectionId(target);
    let attribute = '';
    console.log(sectionId);
  }
}
```

The event fires and the functions run, but the above gives the unexpected following results

//first-coverage-section (this one is expected.)
//undefined (this is expected to be the same, but is not.)

And I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is happening.

Comment: you need to `return` the result of the recursive call in the `else` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that your recursive call is not returning anything.
when you do:

`getSectionId(element.parentElement);`

it will call the function and maybe some day, the if above

```
if(element.hasAttribute('id')){
    console.log(element.id); 
    return element.id;
  }
```

will return something, but that won't be returned to the previous calls therefore  your main call wont have anything to return, so to solve this you need to do this:

```
function getSectionId(target){
  let element = target;
  if(element.hasAttribute('id')){
    console.log(element.id); 
    return element.id;
  } 
  else {
    // add this return and your function will work correctly.
    return getSectionId(element.parentElement);
  }
};
```

basically you have something like this:

```js
function recursiveNotWorking(n) {
  if (n === 5) {
    return "something"
  } else {
    // you dont return anything, then something never bubbles up
    recursiveNotWorking(n + 1);
  }
}

function recursiveWorking(n) {
  if (n === 5) {
    return "something"
  } else {
    // we return something
    return recursiveWorking(n + 1);
  }
}

console.log("NW: ", recursiveNotWorking(1));
console.log("Working: ", recursiveWorking(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `return` in the first function and you don't check on `undefined`. Also you don't need to use the `element` variable. It's useless.
Maybe this will work:

```
function getSectionId(target){
  if (typeof target === 'undefined') return null;
  if(target.hasAttribute('id')){
    console.log(target.id); 
    return target.id;
  } 
  return getSectionId(target.parentElement);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the result of the recursive call:

```
const getSectionId = target => {
  if (target.hasAttribute('id') {
    return target.id;
  }

  // You should also check that parentElement exist
  // Otherwise you might reach the root node and then parentElement could become null

  return getSectionId(target.parentElement);
};
```

Alos, this can be re-written as well as one liner:

```
const getSectionId = t => t.id || getSectionId(t.parentElement)
```